# Among the list of operators such as "?" and "&&" in JSON, what is the meaning of ":"?

Tags: json, operators

Among the list of operators such as "?" and "&&" in JSON, what is the meaning of **":"** ? Example code below (see line 5):
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
"additionalRowClass":
{
"operator": ":",
"operands":
[
{
"operator": "==",
"operands":
[
{
"operator": "%",
"operands":
[
"@rowIndex",
2
]
},
0
]
},
"sp-css-backgroundColor-noFill",
{
"operator": ":",
"operands":
[
{
"operator": "==",
"operands":
[
{
"operator": "%",
"operands":
[
"@rowIndex",
2
]
},
1
]
},
"sp-css-backgroundColor-BgLightGray30",
""
]
}
]
}
}

Comment: JSON doesn’t have operators. What ‘“operator”: “:”’ means in the context of this JSON representation of whatever it is depends on what you’re talking about, which you don’t mention.

Comment: We have no idea what tool is consuming this JSON. Try its documentation for an explanation of what the schema means.

Comment: Apologies! Consumer is SharePoint Online. Context is custom list formatting. Function is alternative row background depending on whether row index is odd or even.  

I see "?" as an operator in this context all the time. ":" I do not understand. Guessing it is the equivalent of a switch statement? When I swap out ":" for "?" it still works.  

Also I see it listed in the list of operators in this JSON spec, but I don't see a definition:
https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json#definitions/

Comment: If my question needs more refining or clarification, happy to oblige. Thank you for responding so quickly!

Comment: The edit has made it much worse. Please format the json appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not a JSON question, we need to see the code that parse and uses the values in the JSON to be able to answer what the ":" value is used for.

The JSON itself doesn't have any operators so the code that uses the JSON is using it's values as operators since its a "key":"value" pair (Dictionary)

Example:
JSON file:

```
{
    <key>:<value>
}
```

The code that uses the file parses this file so you can say for example:

```
var parsed_json = <Parsed json file>
var value = ""

if (parsed_json[<key>] == "Example_value") {
    value = parsed_json[<key]
}
```

In this probably bad example you check if a specific key has the value "Example_value" and set it to that value.

In your case the value is ":" so depending on where it's used in the code that uses this value it can mean anything so we need to see that code to help you with what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

`:` in SharePoint JSON formatting is similar to **Conditional (ternary) operator in JavaScript**.

`:` operator is used in SharePoint JSON formatting when you are using Abstract Tree Syntax (AST) - which is must while using JSON in SharePoint 2019.

**Documentations**:

1. [SharePoint JSON formatting-syntax-reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference)
2. [Conditional (ternary) operator - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)